# Correct usage of PouchDB in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, indexeddb, pouchdb

I tried to store objects in a pouchdb at the client.

creating the DB and fetch all docs is working well.
but when I try to query the DB by db.find() it takes several minutes to get it - also the browser lags and the CPU and RAM increases a lot.

I know there is a fault, but I dont know what I doing wrong.

here the angular pouchDB service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchFind from 'pouchdb-find';
import { IImage } from '../_interfaces/image';
import { ISelector } from '../_interfaces/pouchdb-selector';
PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind);

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PouchdbService {
  public pouchdb = new PouchDB("pouchform");
  
  constructor() {
    this.pouchdb.info().then(function (info) {
      console.log(info);
    })
  }

  insert(content: IImage){
    this.pouchdb.post(content)
  }

  getAll(): Promise<IImage[]>{
    return new Promise<IImage[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.pouchdb.allDocs({include_docs: true, attachments: true})
        .then(data => {
          let rows: any = data.rows
          let images: IImage[] = rows.map(d => d.doc)
          resolve(images)
      })
    })
  }

  query(selector: ISelector): Promise<any>{
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.pouchdb.find({
          selector: selector.selectors // e.g. it is {cam_brand: "Apple"}
        }).then(result => {
          console.log(result)
          resolve(result)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log("err", err)
        })
    })
  }
}
```

the query:

```
this.pouchdb.query({selectors: {cam_brand: "Apple"}}).then(i => {
  console.log("filtered" , i)
})
```

I also tried it to createIndex before, but it doesn't increased the performance

for instance:

- the object includes just the absolute image path (<200 characters) and the camera_brand string
- there are only 400 objects of it in the database, which is quite less

EDIT:
now I tried id directly with indexedDB.
When I add these 400 objects (one by one in a for loop) the loop is finished in milliseconds.
after waiting 2-3mins, the response of the insert occurs.
I guess I have some issue with the indexedDB itself.

I am using Angular 10 with electron if this helps.

EDIT-Electron:
I now migrated pouchdb in a new boilertemplate.
On the "Hot-Reload" functionality on platform:"WEB" its working properly.
But when I build the production of electron, which has the platform win32 its the same slow behaviour
Do i need some special imports to solve this?

Comment: I see `getAll()` is requesting `attachments`.   Are these attachments images? Posting an example of a document would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for answering.
the document look like this.
`{cam_brand: "Apple"
cam_model: "iPhone 7"
date_digitized: "2019:09:07 09:42:29"
date_original: "2019:09:07 09:42:29"
description: null
exif_height: "3024"
exif_width: "4032"
path: "C:\Users\Pictures\Saved Pictures\IMG_1348.jpg"
_id: "013300fd-9cd8-4409-8370-ad3fdd4c0ea6"
_rev: "1-258d99499ddca2d94150cd7cf4d838c7"
}`

Comment: i have some additional information.
When i open the desktop app with a fresh empty database (deleted it previously - it creats a DB on app launch by `new PouchDB('mydb')`) and inserting the documents, the query is very fast (within milliseconds). but when i close the app and open again the query is very slow. is it wrong to creating the instance of `new PouchDB('myDB') ` at every launch of the app?

Comment: sorry i forgot to answer your question. no there is no attachement, just the file path.

Comment: Insert many documents with [bulkDocs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/bulk-operations.html#use-bulkdocs-to-write-many-docs) rather than one-by-one.

Comment: i did now, but it doesnt change the db.find behavour...

Comment: I recommend posting your selector (in the original post not in a comment).  `find()` can be problematic because certain queries - and definitely those not mapping to secondary indexes - are processed in memory.

Comment: Your query is incorrect, it should be `{ selector:...}` not `{ selectors:...}`.

Comment: no it is not, it looks confusing - i know. but selectors is the property of my interface ISeletor.

Comment: Where are you getting the TypeScript ambient that defines such from?

Comment: `npm install --save @types/pouchdb` and `npm install --save @types/pouchdb-find`